# Howto add values in group array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array data structure:

```
[0] => 11111    Order   2121                                                    
[1] => 11111    Order   2121    10.21                           
[2] => 11111    Order   2121                                                
[3] => 11111    Order   2121    -1.11                                   
[4] => 22222    Order   33313   11.00                               
[5] => 22222    Order   33313   -1.45                                                   
[6] => 22222    Order   33313
```

I can get at the values via specifying the field positions via a loop, like so:-

```
    foreach($data as $row) {
    $columns= explode("\t", $row);
    $order_type = $fields[1];
    ...
```

However because I have the same data coming across (11111), I can't figure out howto iterate to get the values in the 4th column, as I'd like to remove the -1.11 from the 10.21 for example, and only show back the total value. Some rows with the same ID are blank, so it's causing me issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned the tabs in to spaces just to make my testing easier:

```
<?php
$data = array(
'11111 Order 2121',
'11111 Order 2121 10.21',
'11111 Order 2121',
'11111 Order 2121 -1.11',
'22222 Order 33313 11.00',
'22222 Order 33313 -1.45',
'22222 Order 33313');

$new = array();
foreach($data as $row){
    $fields = explode(" ",$row);


    if(!empty($fields[3])){
        $new[$fields[0]] += $fields[3];
    }
}
print_r($new);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [11111] => 9.1
    [22222] => 9.55
)
```

working demo: http://codepad.org/MLjwMAiW